# Segmentation fault only when I redirect stdout to /dev/null?

Tags: c++, redirect, segmentation-fault, stdout

I've got a C++ unit test that produces useful output to stderr, and mostly noise (unless I'm debugging) to stdout, so I'd like to redirect the stdout to /dev/null.

Curiously enough, doing this seems to cause a segmentation fault.

Is there any reason why code might seg fault with "> /dev/null" and run fine otherwise?

The output is produced entirely by `printf`s, if that has any bearing.

It is difficult for me to post the offending code because it is research being submitted for publication.  I'm hoping there is an "obvious" possible cause based on this description.

### post mortem

The segfault was being caused by code like this:

```
ArrayElt* array = AllocateArrayOfSize(array_size);
int index = GetIndex(..) % array_size;
ArrayElt elt = array[index];
```

For the umpteenth time, I forgot that `x % y` remains negative when `x` is negative in C/C++.

Ok, so why was it only happening when I redirected to `/dev/null`?  My guess is that the invalid memory address I was accessing was in an output buffer for stdout - and this buffer isn't allocated when it isn't needed.

Thanks for the good answers!

Comment: Is the code multithreaded? If so, it's possible that redirecting stdout could alter that timing of a critical aspect of your program and trigger a race condition bug.

Comment: Not multithreaded.  How do I start gdb on a process with its output redirected?  "gdb ./mybinary > /dev/null" also redirects the stdout of gdb.

Comment: The sign of `x % y` when either operand is negative is implementation-defined, so not that you can't portably rely on the behaviour that you're seeing.

Comment: @Tyler: if you come from LISP-land or somewhere else that requires (x mod y) to return a positive number, then maybe you should write yourself a (template?) function that does the job for you, and use it instead of the operator?  The integer version is easy; you'd probably need to provide one or more specializations for floating point numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no 'normal' reason for I/O to stdout to trigger a core dump when standard output is redirected to /dev/null.

You most probably have a stray pointer or a buffer overflow that triggers the core dump when sent to /dev/null and not when sent to standard output - but it will be hard to spot the problem without the code.

It is conventional to put the useful information on standard output and the noise on standard error.

Answer (score 6):

This doesn't exactly answer your question, but it could. Have you tried using [gdb](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)? It's a command-line debugging tool that can find where segfaults are occurring. It's fairly easy to use. [Here is a pretty in-depth tutorial on how to use it.](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gdb/gdb_toc.html)

Comment: Good idea - I've used it a little before.  When I run "gdb ./my_binary > /dev/null", though, I also lose the interface for gdb - how can I start gdb on my process with its stdout redirected?

Comment: @Tyler: check the options for run within `gdb`: `gdb ./my_binary` on the command line (or add the name of the core dump if you have one), and then run the program with 'run >/dev/null'.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that something is checking "isatty", which might cause different behavior for `/dev/null`.

It might be that something is **reading** from stdout, which would fail for `/dev/null`.

Comment: @Martin: if /dev/null is open for reading, then you can read from it (but you get no information - just 'EOF').  If someone is expecting to read from a nominally write-only channel (that is, the code is reading from standard output), then it has serious problems (but you can often get away with it when standard output is the terminal).